# How to set a date as input in java?

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

Is there any direct way to set a date to a variable but as an input? 
I mean that i don't know the date at design time, the user should give it.
I tried the following code but it doesn't work:
Calendar myDate=new GregorianCalendar(int year, int month , int day);

Comment: Look at the Scanner class for handling user input.

Comment: I do not understand why you mean by "direct way to set a date to a variable but as an input". Can you be more specific?

Comment: I mean if there is a method defined by java takes arguments as variabels and then know sthe values of them at the run time.

Comment: FYI, the [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class is now legacy, replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) in Java 8 and later. Or use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) if you want only the year-month-day without time of day.  `LocalDate.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 )` = January 23, 2018.

Answer (score 10):

## tl;dr

```
 LocalDate.of( 2026 , 1 , 23 )  // Pass: ( year , month , day )
```

## java.time

Some other Answers are correct in showing how to gather input from the user, but use the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `LocalDate`

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2026 , 1 , 23 );
```

Parse your input strings as integers as discussed here: [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585779)

```
int y = Integer.parseInt( yearInput );
int m = Integer.parseInt( monthInput );  // 1-12 for January-December.
int d = Integer.parseInt( dayInput );

LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( y , m , d );
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 9):

Try the following code. I am parsing the entered String to make a Date

```
// To take the input
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the Date ");

String date = scanner.next();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date2=null;
try {
    //Parsing the String
    date2 = dateFormat.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(date2);
```

Comment: Does this way make a real date ? I mean if i insert a wrong date does it accept it ?

Comment: yes ! It does. Please make sure that you are entering the date in right format . I mean for above example 
If I'll enter : 35-MAR-1992
then result will be : Sat Apr 04 00:00:00 PST 1992

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. The `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes used in most of the other answers are poorly designed and long outdated. Don’t use them.

I further suggest that the user wants to enter the date in a short format specific to his or her locale. For this purpose I first declare a few constants:

```
private static final Locale defaultFormattingLocale
        = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT);
private static final String defaultDateFormat = DateTimeFormatterBuilder
        .getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT, null, 
                IsoChronology.INSTANCE, defaultFormattingLocale);
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(defaultDateFormat, defaultFormattingLocale);
```

Now prompting for and reading the date goes like this:

```
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    LocalDate sampleDate
            = Year.now().minusYears(1).atMonth(Month.NOVEMBER).atDay(26);
    System.out.println("Enter date in " + defaultDateFormat
            + " format, for example " + sampleDate.format(dateFormatter));
    String dateString = inputScanner.nextLine();
    try {
        LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
        System.out.println("Date entered was " + inputDate);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.out.println("Invalid date: " + dateString);
    }
```

Sample session in US locale:

```
Enter date in M/d/yy format, for example 11/26/20
2/9/21
Date entered was 2021-02-09
```

Sample session in Danish locale:

```
Enter date in dd/MM/y format, for example 26/11/2020
9/februar/2021
Invalid date: 9/februar/2021
```

In the last case you will probably want to allow the user to try again. I am leaving that to you.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Nice! **For future visitors:** In the code given above, the `Locale` used with `dateFormatter` doesn't necessarily have to be the same one as used to obtain `defaultDateFormat`. For example, `String format = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.FULL, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.FRANCE); LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); System.out.println(now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format, Locale.ENGLISH))); System.out.println(now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format, Locale.FRANCE)));`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try my simple code below :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String strDate = input.nextLine();

try
{
   Date date = dateInput.parse(strDate);
   System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date));
} 
catch (ParseException e) 
{
   System.out.println("Parce Exception");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 2):

**Check this out:)**

```
 ZoneId defaultZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.print("Enter the DOB: ");
 String dobString = scanner.nextLine();

 LocalDate dobLocal = LocalDate.parse(dobString);
 Date dob = Date.from(dobLocal.atStartOfDay(defaultZoneId).toInstant());
 System.out.println(dob);
```

Simple project GitHub Repo: https://github.com/lojithv/Java-Enter-Student-Details.git

[image]

You should enter dob like this : yyyy-mm-dd

Done:)

Answer (score 1):

I have modified @SK08 answer and created a method which takes year, month and date as input from the user and returns date.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str[] = {"year", "month", "day" };
    String date = "";

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter " + str[i] + ": ");
        date = date + scanner.next() + "/";
    }
    date = date.substring(0, date.length()-1);
    System.out.println("date: "+ date); 

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date parsedDate = null;

    try {
        parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return parsedDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a repost of a comment. I give Arvind Kumar Avinash full credit. @arvindkumaravinash
"Nice! For future visitors: In the code given above, the Locale used with dateFormatter doesn't necessarily have to be the same one as used to obtain defaultDateFormat. For example,

```
String format = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
        FormatStyle.FULL, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.FRANCE);
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(
        now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format, Locale.ENGLISH)));
System.out.println(
        now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format, Locale.FRANCE)));
```

"
For Americans, be sure to replace FRANCE with US, the British use UK, and so on. here is a list of currently used countries.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html

Also be sure to import all packages necessary separately, because time* will not work for this. So these essentially

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.time.chrono.IsoChronology;
```

Comment: I just want arvind to get some credit and include that if you are not in FRANCE you need to put the correct country. @arvind

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine and you can validate the date  as well using setlenient function-

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Datinput {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n;
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();
        String da[] = new String[n];
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        Date date[] = new Date[n];
        in.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < da.length; i++) {
            da[i] = in.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < da.length; i++) {

            try {
                date[i] = sdf.parse(da[i]);
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working I tried!

```
package javaapplication2;
//@author Ibrahim Yesilay
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication2 {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Scanner giris = new Scanner(System.in);        
        System.out.println("gün:");
        int d = giris.nextInt();
        System.out.println("ay:");
        int m = giris.nextInt();
        System.out.println("yil:");
        int y = giris.nextInt();
        String tarih;
        tarih = Integer.toString(d) + "/" + Integer.toString(m) + "/" + Integer.toString(y);  
        System.out.println("Tarih : " + tarih); 
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date girilentarih = null;
        girilentarih = dateFormat.parse(tarih);
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(girilentarih));      
    }   
}
```